# This expression(terminate) is used for which purpose?

Tags: laravel

My terminate middleware as below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

    class ExampleMiddleware
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
        {
            if ($role == null) {
                return redirect('/deneme');
            }
            return $next($request);
        }
        public function terminate($request, $response)
        {
           sleep(4);//what is the purpose in this section(What this means is that anyone who has used this way?)
        }
    }
```

What is the purpose of the terminate function, what is it and when should it be used?

Comment: why would we understand your undocumented code. ask the author why it's there.

sleep() waits for a certain amount of time

Comment: I know this code is waiting. I am asking the purpose of the terminate function.

Comment: read the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#terminable-middleware

Comment: I have already read sample no use

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes a middleware may need to do some work after the HTTP response has been prepared. For example, the "session" middleware included with Laravel writes the session data to storage after the response has been fully prepared. If you define a terminate method on your middleware, it will automatically be called after the response is ready to be sent to the browser.

[Terminable Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#terminable-middleware)